# How to set JDK system variables path for portable android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, system-paths

I am trying to use Android Studio in the computer where I don't have administrator permissions
I downloaded Android Studio portable and JDK portable which I extracted and ready to set the variable for, but I can't.
When I start Android studio it gives an error about not finding Java.
Is there a way to set it without having the admin permissions?

Comment: try using cmd/command line/terminal if admin has not restricted it..google how to set path from command line

Comment: Already tried that and it is restricted :(